# FluentWait in Selenium automated Testing

Tags: java, selenium

I am using the code below, which I got from a StackOverflow answer:

```java
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
    .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("my-css-selector")).getText().contains("name");
    }
});
```

Eclipse is showing an error on "until". When I hover the mouse on it it says:

> The method `until(Function<? super WebDriver,T>)` in the type `Wait<WebDriver>` is not applicable for the arguments `(new Function<WebDriver,Boolean>(){})`

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be fine, Its just that you might have used the wrong import for Function.

You may want to go with:-

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
            .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

wait.until(new com.google.common.base.Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return null;
    }
});
```